# Could you help me to find a model for this curve?

Tags: plane-curves, mathematical-modeling

I am very bad in mathematics and I'm not able to find by myself the model corresponding to this kind of curve.

[image]

I wish to have a quick growth at the beginning, then it should increase slowly for a long time and then a quick growth until the end value (here at 10).

This curve represents the basic learning curve: You learn a lot of things at the beginning then you have a time when you don't improve a lot (you are in fact memorizing what you've learnt) and then you become better and better.

Could someone give me a function / model to match this curve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like :

```
tanh(x/150)*4+(arctan((x-700)/100)+PI/2)*2
```

with this result :

[image: picture]

The $\tanh$ gives the growing part at the left and the $\arctan$ the inflection (at $700$).

---

Using $\tanh$ alone seems better :

```
tanh(x/120)*5+(tanh((x-670)/150)+1)*2.5
```

[image: tanh]

Some 'tuning' may be useful.

Other functions of this kind are [sigmoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (see this [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Gjl-t%28x%29.svg)).

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was looking for :)

Comment: @MARTINDamien: You are welcome!